# Is it possible to align different parts of an x label in different ways in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In `matplotlib`, is it possible to get and `xlabel` like the following one:

```
+--------------------+
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
+--------------------+
L       center       R
```

I mean, `L` should be left aligned (to the begin of the axis), `center` should be centered and `R` should be right aligned (to the end of the axis).

Right now I get the number of spaces `n1` and `n2` by trial and error:

```
set_xlabel('L'+(' '*n1)+'center'+(' '*n2)+'R')
```

Comment: why not just add text? I mean instead of having 3 xlabel, just stick with ``center`` as xlabel and L and R as text

Answer (score 1):

### Using `plt.text`

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlabel('center')
plt.text(0.12, 0.035, 'L', transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)
plt.text(0.90, 0.035, 'R', transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)
```

[image]

### Using `ax.twiny`

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlabel('center')

xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
axL = ax.twiny()
axL.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
axL.xaxis.set_label_position('bottom')
axL.set_xlabel('L', loc='left')
axL.set_xticks([xmin, xmax])
axL.set_xticklabels([' ', ' '])
axR = ax.twiny()
axR.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
axR.xaxis.set_label_position('bottom')
axR.set_xlabel('R', loc='right')
axR.set_xticks([xmin, xmax])
axR.set_xticklabels([' ', ' '])
```

[image]